# Android Studio app does not fit on screen

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio and can't seem to fix my app not fitting on my screen. I'm using Honor 8 for testing how the app looks and works but parts don't fit. I have tried including activity_main for different screen densities and and screen sizes, but nothing seems to work. Would appreciate some help.

Can not include images yet so here is manifest and activity_main.xml.

activity_main.xml:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageRel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:text="Press" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputRel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageRel"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:width="170dp"
            android:hint="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameTxt"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:width="170dp"
            android:hint="Email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailTxt"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:width="170dp"
            android:password="true"
            android:hint="Password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reenterTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/passwordTxt"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:width="170dp"
            android:password="true"
            android:hint="Re-Enter Password" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genderTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reenterTxt"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Gender:" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/genderTxt"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioOther"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Other" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/countryTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Country:" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countryTxt"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/licenseRel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inputRel"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/licenseTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/license_text" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/licenseCheck"
            android:layout_below="@+id/licenseTxt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="I Agree" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_below="@id/inputRel"/>


</RelativeLayout>`
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.RegistrationApp">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You may want to look into using [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) (or possibly `ScrollView`, depending on the behavior you want).

Comment: Constraint layout gave me the same problem.

Comment: Do you want to achieve the screen is responsive to all devices?

Comment: If it is possible.